# C# DateTime falls within the last 24 hours

Tags: c#

I have a `DateTime` object that I'd like to check and see if it falls within the last 24 hours.

I did something like this but its wrong:

```
myDateTime > DateTime.Now.AddHours(-24) && myDateTime < DateTime.Now
```

where did I go wrong?

Comment: Define "it's wrong"... at first glance it looks OK... tried AddDays(-1) ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code that you posted, so whatever you did wrong is somewhere else in the code.

I only see two minor flaws in the code, but they only affect corner cases:

You should avoid getting the `DateTime.Now` property repeatedly in the code. Its value changes, so you may get inconsistent results in some cases when the values changes from one use to the next.

To get a time interval you would usually pair one inclusive and one exclusive operator, like `>` and `<=`, or `>=` and `<`. That way you can check for intervals next to each other, like 0 - 24 hours and 24 - 28 hours, without getting a gap or an overlap.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
if (myDateTime > now.AddHours(-24) && myDateTime <= now)
```

Comment: I dont understand the optimization technique your talking about, could you explain with some code please?

Comment: @Gully Monsta: I added an example above. However, this isn't any optimisation, it's just avoiding possible inconsistencies in the code.

Comment: Another minor thing is that it should use `UTCNow`. I think `Now` exhibits a bit strange behavior when switching from/to DST. Not sure if this affects this code.

Answer (score 13):

1. Only get `DateTime.Now` once within the function - otherwise the value might change.
2. Use `<=`, not `<`. if you check a microsecond after the time has been set, it will still be equal to `DateTime.Now`. I actually ran into this in production code where imports wouldn't show up in a different query that checked `<` because the import was too fast!

Use this code:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime yesterday = now.AddDays(-1);
if (myDateTime > yesterday && myDateTime <= now) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: nice explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Learning from both the above answers and also to improve the readability of the code we can use a method like this.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
            
        DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Parse("2021-08-25T20:20:19.5540211");
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime yesterday = now.AddHours(-24);
        
        if (IsBewteenTwoDates(myDateTime, yesterday, now))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("this date ({0}) is between {1} & {2}", myDateTime, yesterday, now);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("this date ({0}) is not between {1} & {2}", myDateTime, yesterday, now);
        }   
    }
    
    // Checks if the DateTime object dt is between start and end DateTime.
    public static bool IsBewteenTwoDates(DateTime dt, DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        return dt >= start && dt <= end;
    }
}
```

Check the fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2p2Rsn).